# send a command via a website to a windows server

Tags: php, iis, web-server, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there an interface or something else which provides a connection between a website and a windows server to send commands via the website to the server and the server itself perfoms it? 
I want to generate a context menu on my webpage. In the menu I want to be able to specify some parameter which the server should perform. 
E.g. I perform a rightclick on my webpage, the menu opens and I choose to create a folder on the server with a specific name and path. The server then recieves the command and does exactly what I told him via the webpage. 
My webpage is getting published via the IIS and my Server OS is a Windows Server2012.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To address the most basic part of your question:

Yes, you can send commands to a Windows Server from a web interface using the [PowerShell Web Access feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/canberrapfe/archive/2013/02/17/powershell-web-access-very-quick-start-yep-powershell-in-your-web-browser.aspx) in Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2.

---

For what you want (linking a user control in a web page to the execution of a specific action on the server), you might want to look into executing PowerShell from ASP.NET as outlined in [this article](http://jeffmurr.com/blog/?p=142).

StackOverflow is without doubt a better place to ask questions about ASP.NET than here